# Trouble assigning user access levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following [this](https://gustavocguimaraes.wordpress.com/2014/12/17/role-based-authorization-with-rails-4-enum/) tutorial, as I wanted to learn how to create user authorization with singular roles (each user has one role) from scratch rather than using a gem like rolify that does it all for me, but I'm hung up on assigning the users access levels.

When I type erin = User.find(9) in the console it finds my test@test.com user. I try to issue the erin.admin! command but it throws an error about the password? (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank).

I've also tried erin.access_level = "admin" which returns "admin" while I'm still in the console but no longer exists when I exit the console, fire up the rails server and try to test out my test@test.com user in my app.

Is there any other way to assign access levels? Am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User record cannot be saved because a validation exists that requires a password. I don't know if there are special rules for the format of the password, but you can easily set a password so that you can save the user:

```
user = User.find(9)
user.password = 'Test1234'
user.password_confirmation = 'Test1234' # you might need this as well
user.access_level = 'admin'
user.save #=> true
```

If `user.save` returns false, check `user.errors` for any other validation errors that would cause the record not to save.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you :) I definitely need more practice using the console. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I have another question, how do I get the user access levels to my deployed app on heroku? I did git push heroku master and I ran the migrations, but the database doesn't seem to touch the deployed app so my test@test.com user doesn't have admin access levels on the deployed app.

Comment: Did you run the migrations on heroku: `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Yep, ran heroku run rake db:migrate and it looks like it completed the migration

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of my question, where my database didn't seem to deploy to Heroku, it's because I was working in the dev db, not the production db.

To do that, I ran "heroku run rails console" and then followed the above steps to give a user admin access levels. More here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#console